# Create JSON String using GSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am having a class like following,

```
public class Student {
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public int age;    
}
```

Now I want to create new Student,

```
//while create new student
Student stu = new Student();
stu.age = 25;
stu.name = "Guna";
System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(stu));
```

This gives me the following output,

```
{"id":0,"name":"Guna","age":25} //Here I want string without id, So this is wrong
```

So here I want String like

```
{"name":"Guna","age":25}
```

If I want to edit old Student

```
//While edit old student
Student stu2 = new Student();
stu2.id = 1002;
stu2.age = 25;
stu2.name = "Guna";
System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(stu2));
```

Now the output is

```
{"id":1002,"name":"Guna","age":25} //Here I want the String with Id, So this is correct
```

How can I make a JSON String with a field [At some point], without a field [at some point].

Any help will be highly appreciable.

Thanks.

Comment: When you declare an int variable, its default value is 0. An int could not be null. So I advise you to use a String instead or to ignore the id value if it is 0.

Comment: @joao2fast4u I have edited my code friend

Comment: @Gunaseelan Check my answer for better solution. You no need to remove key after creating json.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Better is to use @expose annotation like

```
public class Student {
    public int id;
    @Expose
    public String name;
    @Expose
    public int age;
}
```

And use below method to get Json string from your object

```
private String getJsonString(Student student) {
    // Before converting to GSON check value of id
    Gson gson = null;
    if (student.id == 0) {
        gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
        .create();
    } else {
        gson = new Gson();
    }
    return gson.toJson(student);
}
```

It will ignore id column if that is set to 0, either it will return json string with id field.

Comment: Yes, I think This is the better answer. Thanks bro

Comment: what if I have an Object as one of the properties of the class, and I have implemented Gson in that object?

Answer (score 3):

You can explore the json tree with gson.

Try something like this :

```
gson.toJsonTree(stu1).getAsJsonObject().remove("id");
```

You can add some properties also :

```
gson.toJsonTree(stu2).getAsJsonObject().addProperty("id", "100");
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two options.

- Use Java's transient keyword which is to indicate that a field should not be serialized. Gson will exclude it automatically. This may not work for you as you want it conditionally.
- Use @Expose annotation for the fields that you want and initialize your Gson builder as following:

  `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();`

So you need to mark name and age fields using @Expose and you need to have two different Gson instances  for the default one which includes all fields and the one above which excludes fields without `@Expose` annotation.

Answer (score 2):

```
JsonObject jsObj =  (JsonObject) new Gson().toJsonTree(stu2);
jsObj.remove("age"); // remove field 'age'
jsObj.addProperty("key", "value"); // add field 'key'

System.out.println(jsObj);
```

You can manipulate with JsonObject

Answer (score 2):

You should introduce additional field to `Student` class that will notice `GSON` about `id` serialization policy.
Then, you should implement custom serializer that will implement `TypeAdapter`. In your `TypeAdapter` implementation according to id serialization policy you will serialize it or not. Then you should register your `TypeAdapter` in GSON factory:

```
GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
gson.registerTypeAdapter(Student.class, new StudentTypeAdapter());
```

Hope this helps.