# Is there any ways to save external file "information" into array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, filereader

e.g: (I took the first line of the external file)

```
Giant, Colgate Toothpaste, 4.50
```

I want to separate & save them in an array like this before/after I send them to the object & ArrayList.

```
mall[i] = "Giant";
product[i] = "Colgate Toothpaste";
price[i] = 4.50
```

p/s: I think I should do that because I need to alter the price in the future. 
This is how my coding looks like right now.

```
public static void readFile(ArrayList<Product> productList) throws Exception {
        try {
            productList.clear(); //clear the list! or remove all elements from the list!
            // Coding Here
        }
        catch(Exception e) { System.err.println(e.getMessage());}
    }
```

Below is the content of the "product.in" file (external file)

```
Giant, Colgate Toothpaste, 4.50
Giant, Dashing Deodorant, 6.55
Giant, Adidas Deodorant, 7.55
Giant, Dettol Hand-sanitiser, 10.00
Giant, Sokubutso Shower Foam, 15.00
Tesco, Colgate Toothpaste, 4.55
Tesco, Dettol Hand-sanitiser, 7.00
Tesco, Sokubutso Shower Foam, 15.05
Tesco, Adidas Deodorant, 7.45
Tesco, Dashing Deodorant, 5.45
TF, Sokubutso Shower Foam, 15.05
TF, Dettol Hand-sanitiser, 9.50
TF, Adidas Deodorant, 8.55
TF, Dashing Deodorant, 7.55
TF, Colgate Toothpaste, 5.00
```

If you think I provide you less information, just reply to this thread about it. I'll provide more.

`edited: add product class`

```
class Product {
    private String store;
    private String item;
    private double price;

    public Product(String store, String item, double price) {
        this.setStore(store);
        this.setItem(item);
        this.setPrice(price);
    }
```

Comment: The magic keyword is JSON. 
Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26605763/create-json-string-using-gson

Comment: Why not omit the arrays and just turn each line directly into a `Product`?  Certainly you should be able to alter the price of a `Product` later if necessary?

Comment: @Melvin I don't think that I can use JSON as the external file (product.in) has been preformatted like in the thread above.

Comment: @KevinAnderson I've been updating the product class into the thread. I can't omit the arrays because of it. I need to send 3 data to Product class

Comment: I think I should separate them before sending them to another class

Comment: Well, yes, you need to separate the three pieces of data in each lnput line, but there's no reason you can't then immediately create a `Product` object from those three pieces of data, add that `Product` to the product list, and then move on to the next line.  There's really no need to accumulate arrays of _all_ the malls, _all_ the product [names], _all_ the prices, before starting to construct `Product`s.  That said, you certainly can do it that way, if you really want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain implementation without extra libraries like OpenCSV or similar would be

1. Read the file line by line using `BufferedReader` and `try-with-resources` to make sure the file resource is closed automatically upon processing.
2. Split each line using `String.split` into columns
3. Create a `Product` item from the columns and add it to the list
4. Return the result list.

Aside note: it would be better to use price in `int` cents than in double because the floating-point arithmetics is known to be imprecise.

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
// ...

public static List<Product> readFile(String csvFile) throws Exception {
    List<Product> result = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) {
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] cols = line.split("\\s*,\\s*"); // split by comma and optional spaces
            assert cols.length > 2;  // make sure the line contains at least 3 columns
            Product product = new Product(cols[0], cols[1], Double.parseDouble(cols[2]));
            result.add(product);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }
   
    return result;
}
```